# Is there a Gradle plugin to format a build.gradle file?

Tags: gradle, format, build.gradle

Is there a Gradle plugin that could format or check the format of my *build.gradle* files? My project is getting bigger with several subprojects and I would like to make them follow the same format/structure.

Comment: If you are using, IntelliJ you should be able to specify format in your IDE settings. I think same should exist for Eclipse also.

Comment: You can use Sublime text with Gradle syntax plugin installed - it will highlight keywords and provide auto-complete. If you are on Windows, you can use Notepad++ with [this](https://gist.github.com/toddb/2870655) language definition. Don't know any other programs/plugins.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/toddb/2870655

Answer (score 4):

You can add a "user defined language" file, with the gradle syntax

1. Download a gradle language-file. You may use this: https://gist.github.com/ksnortum/7568627
2. Open the Notepad++. Go to "Menu -> Language -> Define Your Language"
3. In the dialog, click "import", and select xml file
4. Restart Notepad++

Comment: Please let us know if any formatting option is available and not syntax. I want to format existing gradle files.

Answer (score 3):

The [spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/tree/main/plugin-gradle) gradle plugin can be used to format or check the formatting of `build.gradle` files. Simple config below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.18.0'
}

spotless {
    groovyGradle {
        target '*.gradle'
        greclipse()
    }
}
```

With the above config, the `spotlessApply` gradle task can be used to format .gradle files and the `spotlessCheck` task can be used to check for formatting violations.